# Pandas: batch subsitution of values from different rows meeting same criterias

Tags: python, pandas, batch-processing

I have extracted some data in pandas format from a sql server. The structure like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day':(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),'State':('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'),'Direction':('N','S','N','S','N','S','N','S'),'values':(12,34,22,37,14,16,23,43)})

 >>> df
    Day Direction State  values
0    1         N     A      12
1    2         S     A      34
2    3         N     A      22
3    4         S     A      37
4    1         N     B      14
5    2         S     B      16
6    3         N     B      23
7    4         S     B      43
```

Now I want to substitute all values with same day and same Direction but with (State == A) by itself + values with same day and same State but with (State == B). For example, like this:

```
df.loc[(df.Day == 1) & (df.Direction == 'N') & (df.State == 'A'),'values'] = df.loc[(df.Day == 1) & (df.Direction == 'N') & (df.State == 'A'),'values'].values + df.loc[(df.Day == 1) & (df.Direction == 'N') & (df.State == 'B'),'values'].values

>>> df
   Day Direction State  values
0    1         N     A      26
1    2         S     A      34
2    3         N     A      22
3    4         S     A      37
4    1         N     B      14
5    2         S     B      16
6    3         N     B      23
7    4         S     B      43
```

Notice the first line values have been changed from 12 to 26(12 + 14)
Since the values are from different rows, so kind of difficult to use combine_first functions?

Now I have to use two loops (on 'Day' and on 'Direction') and the above attribution sentence to do, it's extremely slow when the dataframe's getting big. Do you have any smart and efficient way doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first define a function to do add values from B to A in the same group. Then apply this function to each group.

```
def f(x):
    x.loc[x.State=='A','values']+=x.loc[x.State=='B','values'].iloc[0]
    return x

df.groupby(['Day','Direction']).apply(f)
Out[94]: 
   Day Direction State  values
0    1         N     A      26
1    2         S     A      50
2    3         N     A      45
3    4         S     A      80
4    1         N     B      14
5    2         S     B      16
6    3         N     B      23
7    4         S     B      43
```

Comment: oh, groupby and apply: lovely mate of funcs. As a newbie, always feel awesome about what they can do, but still need more training to master them. Many Thanks, dude

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.